# Is there a way to make this PostgreSQL query more efficient?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to craft a simple query where the first name and last name columns are displayed along with the email, and show only the results where the password length is less than 12 characters.

```
SELECT fname  || ' ' || lname fullname, email, LENGTH(password) passwordlen FROM users WHERE LENGTH(password)<12 ORDER BY passwordlen;
```

`LENGTH(password)` has to be written out twice, rather than being referenced twice using `passwordlen`. Is there another way to write out this query to be less redundant or more efficient that I'm missing? Maybe using subqueries?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: you can check the execution plan.  This looks typical, and should not cause the server to do much more work.

Comment: Are you asking about performance, or about the fact that you have to repeat `LENGTH(password)` twice? Most RDBMSs won't allow you to use an alias in a group by or where clause.

Comment: @Andrew The second part - having to repeat LENGTH(password) twice. OK, that's good to know! Just wanted to be sure that there wasn't another way to write this to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks to you both.

Comment: You should be able to leave it to the query compiler to notice that once it has checked the length, it has the length. The [documentation for Character Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) appears to imply that the length of the string is stored, so it doesn't have to measure it when you use it anyway.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the intention is to leave out results that are over a certain number of characters to ensure only relevant results are pulled :-)

Comment: @SarahConway I thought your concern was having `LENGTH(password)` in there twice, so I was saying that the compiler is very likely to notice that and make an appropriate optimisation for you. There is no need for you to try to do anything about that in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, just maybe, an index might help:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_password_lenght ON users(LENGTH(password));
```

But it depends on the number of records, the distribution of the length and the exact query if this really helps. Check the query plan.

But, how come that you have such short passwords? And these are definitely not stored as an MD5 of SHA256 hash either. Please check your security policy.

Comment: This is for an example scenario to illustrate how-to, not a real-life production database :-) Thank you for your concern. I just wanted to make sure there isn't a better way to approach this type of problem. Appreciate the suggestion, also!